# sync subcategory in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

i made products and categories and sub categories

when i do sync them , product and category save in the category_prodcts.
but sub category shows a error message :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'subcategory_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `category_products` (`category_id`, `product_id`) values (1, 1))
```

and these are my codes :

```
productController:



$data->cats()->sync($request->cats,false);
$data->subcategory()->sync($request->subcategory,false);
```

Product Model:

```
public function CATS(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_products',
        'product_id', 'category_id');
    }
    
    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SubCategory::class,
            'category_products','subcategory_id','category_id' );
    }
```

subcategory Model:

```
   public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class,'subcategory_products',
            'category_id','subcategory_id');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
```

category model:

```
    public function subcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Subcategory::class,
        'category_subcategory', 'category_id', 'subcategory_id' );
}
```

category_product database:

```
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('subcategory_id');
    $table->foreign('product_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('products')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('category_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('categories')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('subcategory_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('categories')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->primary(['category_id','product_id','subcategory_id']);

enter code here
```

thanks for your help

Comment: what is `$data` ? could you `dd($data)`

Comment: $data is for another records and save them

Comment: when i dd($request->subcategory) it shows zero!!!